# Storing a state of a dialog box

Tags: qt

if I have a dialog box with some checkboxes, some ratiobuttons etc, and I select some of them after I close this dialog and open it again all checkboxes are unchecked. What is the best way to store the state of this dialog box?

Comment: Within the same application session, or after the computer has been rebooted?

Comment: @Dave both would do just fine ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the state while the app is running - simply keep the dialog around and show/hide it as necessary.

If you need to keep state for next time the app is run then you need to store the individual settings separately (see QSettings) - this makes sense if say an update of your app add new settings.